# Giphy SDK does not work with proguard / r8 enabled

Tags: android, proguard, android-r8, giphy

When opening DialogFragment Gif with proguard / r8 enabled, the following message appears: "OH NO! SOMETHING WENT WRONG". What should I configure to work normally?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

add this lines to your proguard rules file:

```
-keep class com.giphy.sdk.** {*;}
-keep class com.giphy.sdk.**
-keepclassmembers com.giphy.sdk.** { *; }
```

Comment: The syntax require keyword `class` after `-keep`, so the rule should be `-keep class com.giphy.sdk.** {*;}`. The other two lines are not needed as they does not add anything. Now this rule is very quite broad, and defeats the purpose of shrinking that library. I suggest that you open an issue with Giphy SDK. If they provide an Android library they should ensure that their aar contains the rules required by the library.

Comment: @sgjesse thanks for your comment, I missed class keywords.

Comment: Thanks @feridok. One question for you: Any particulair reason why you don't think the the first rule that you have shouldn't be enough? The first should keep all classes with all members in the package `com.giphy.sdk`, whereas the next two should keep be strict subsets of that.